# Htaccess for url rewrite with one variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteRule page/([0-9]+)$ page.php?id=$1
```

It works, but the included links like css or js don't work. `page/` is seen like a folder, so the links (example: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/default.css" />`) aren't found.

Another example: if "id" doesn't exist i do this `ErrorDocument 403 /notfound.php`, but you are redirected to `domain.com/page/notfound.php`. How i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule page/([0-9]+)$ page.php?id=$1
```

This will redirect only if the requested file or directory does not realy exists.

More informations on [mod_rewrite here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

**Edit :**

As for you issue with resources not beeing found, you will have to add the base tag to you head section in you html page :

```
<base href="/">
```

More informations about the [base tag here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

Comment: Tnx for the reply but not work I had already tried this. but internal links are not found because PAGE/ is seen as a folder

Comment: I wrote my answer before you edit you question with new informations, see my edit now